# QGIS Installer switch to set target directory

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

Can anyone please describe the command line switches that can be used when installing using the stand alone installer for ms windows. As far as I know one could use /S for a silent but I'm pretty sure there are other options as well such as choice of target directory but I just can't find them.

Comment: Does /h or /? list the options?

Comment: Unfortunately not (version 2.18.3).